# How to load a file path as URL to view it on wkwebview in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have an epub file in the project and I would like to open it with in the application i have tried using "EpubExtractor" pod but no use.
Now I am trying to achive that if i can use the path to view that file on the webview.

```
guard let resourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sway",withExtension: "epub") else {return}
webView.loadFileURL(resourceUrl,allowingReadAccessTo: resourceUrl)
```

path I am getting.

```
file:///Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4203B9E1-E3A4-4636-8750-E5340AAD51ED/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3BF662A-34AD-44C0-AFD9-E4BB7AD74551/EpubWebView.app/Sway.epub
```

When I am using the above code i am not able to view anything on the webview as it gives me an error "not able to load in webview"

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Comment: The *path* **is** an URL

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You need to provide more info here. What exactly are you trying to do?   What result are you getting that is not what you expect. Most people here are not mind readers.

Comment: @BlueskyMed can you check now!! I have updated it!!

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but I can find no evidence that Safari or WKWebView support the ePub format. They do support HTML, Microsoft docs, and PDF among other but not ePub.

Comment: @BlueskyMed Okay, I do understand. Any approach of opening an epubfile with in app it might be in any way I have tried using pods like EPubkit... Anny suggestions and references will be highly appreciable

Answer (score -1):

ePub format is not supported by the WKWebView framework. You can search Apple or webkit.org to see the core features of WKWebView